# How can I add a slide effct to this div's changer

Tags: jquery

Please help add slide effect when changing divs (I found example code here):

```
$(function () {
    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('#update1, #update2, #update3');
    function showDiv () {
        divs.hide()
            .filter(function (index) { return index == counter % 3; })
            .show('fast');
        counter++;
    };
    showDiv();  
    setInterval(function () {
        showDiv();
    }, 10 * 1000);  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your could change this line:

```
.show('fast');
```

to use jQuery's animate method:

```
.css({opacity:0}).animate({opacity:1}, "fast");
```

check out the docs for animate [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: could you give me the html or a link and I can check it out a little more?